# pure virtual function needs to take different parameters

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have the following Base Class.

```
class Furniture
{
public:
    virtual void Collapse() = 0;
};
```

With derived classes:

```
class Table : public Furniture
{
public:
    void Collapse() 
    { 
       Save(my_file);
    }
protected:
    void Save(char* filepath);

private:
    char* my_file;
};

class Armoire : public Furniture
{
public:
    void Collapse()
    {
       Save(my_file);
    }
protected:
    void Save(char* filepath);
private:
    char* my_file;
};

class Chair : public Furniture
{
public:
    void Collapse()
    {
       Save(); // note - no filepath
    }
protected:
    void Save();
};
```

After reading the comments, I have edited this question somewhat, to describe more accurately the problem in hand.

My problem is that all but one of the classes derived from `Furniture` define the `Save()` function with a parameter, like `Table` and `Armoire` are doing. It's only the `Chair` class that defines a `Save()` function with no parameter.

I want to somehow move the declaration of the `Save()` function - to be part of an interface, and have the derived classes provide the implementation. But that one class `Chair` that does not require a parameter means that I can't do this.

What is the best way to design this?

Comment: That does not sound like much of a problem, really. In a "pure" OOP design, base methods are always chosen such that derived classes use all parameters, but "pure OOP" is only a means to an end. Note that adding an overload with no parameters would only make the situation worse, because then clients of `Furniture` would never know which `Collapse` to call.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Override number of parameters of pure virtual functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2919584/override-number-of-parameters-of-pure-virtual-functions)

Comment: Since the question arises only if anyone wants to call `Collapse` on a `Furniture` expression (as opposed to a `Table` expression), it would help if you explain how `Furtinure` is actually used. You state that some implementations ignore `filepath`. But if the meaning of `filepath` depends so much on the actual concrete class type, how does the caller know which value makes sense to pass in anyway?

Comment: @hvd, please see my edits - I've described more clearly how this problem is manifested.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I would actually say that it should not be part of the interface of a caller is not supposed to be able to call `Save()`. Can you explain what benefit you see in making it part of the interface? Perhaps those benefits are also obtainable some other way.

Comment: Ignore argument of `Chair::Save(char *filepath)` in its implementation.

Comment: I've considered it yes, but ignoring an argument seems "wrong" somehow. a bit misleading. or is it considered good design... ?

Comment: When you run into issues like this, you really have to ask yourself if you need to be doing it in an object oriented way.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode, what's another alternative?

Comment: @patchwork a `save_furniture` function that dispatches to some non-virtual method depending on a `dynamic_cast`, or something completely different again. There's plenty of ways you could do it.

Answer (score -2):

Use a default parameter in the base class:

`virtual void Collapse( int seconds = 0 ) = 0;`

Comment: First, this does not solve the "problem" but only makes it worse. As a client of `Furniture`, how do I know whether to pass seconds or not if this depends on the concrete type of the derived class which I don't know? Second, putting default arguments into a virtual functions is always a bad idea. You should split it into a public non-virtual and a private virtual function. The public one can then safely provide a default argument.